# spring-cloud-sleuth integration with spring-amqp

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am just making first steps with `spring-cloud-sleuth` and it works just fine with all kinds of http calls.

Now I am trying to look at covering the messaging part as well. I saw that `spring-cloud-sleuth` integrates with `spring-integration` out-of-the-box. I am currently using just `spring-amqp`. Is there also a way to get this working. Does anyone have some insights or even code samples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently we support only AMQP directly via the spring-integration. In order to support AMQP you'd have to ensure that all messages sent have proper headers set and when you get them back you have to take those headers and put them into the local context. Injecting Span (tracing) information to the message is done for example here -https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessagingSpanTextMapInjector.java and extracting tracing data from the message is here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessagingSpanTextMapExtractor.java. In this method you have the setting of the extracted Span into the context https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceChannelInterceptor.java#L71

UPDATE:

With Sleuth 2.0.x (Finchley release train) it should work out of the box if you have a bean of rabbit template type (see [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/instrumentation/spring-rabbit)). No additional code would be necessary.

Comment: There is support now? I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp`

Comment: With 2.0.x it should work out of the box if you have a bean of rabbit template type

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak the provided github links are dead, can you check them?